# How to only receive get file changed by revision In perforce P4

Tags: perforce

In P4, I only want to pull file changed my client workspace from server. But When I use "p4 sync", this command get all files from server. So, How to get files changed  from list revision ? with the files were existed on local and not changed, the command P4 sync do not need sync. My command is here:

```
p4 sync -f //depot/...@Revision
```

Comment: -f stands for force, so remove that from your command. It should do the work.

Comment: I removed -f, the files in my workspace not updated if I deleted that files from my local

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restore a file you deleted with `p4 delete file`, use `p4 revert file`, not `p4 sync`. `p4 sync` is for getting the changes that **other** people made to the files, not for altering the changes that **you** made.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different reasons that the files in your workspace might differ from the current head revision in the depot:

1. A new revision has been submitted to the depot since the last time you synced.
2. You have opened the files (e.g. with `p4 edit`) and made changes to them that are not yet submitted.
3. You have modified the read-only synced files in your workspace without opening them.

(You don't say in your question which of these is the case, which is why you've gotten a couple of different answers that are based on different assumptions about your workspace state -- I'm guessing it's #3, personally, but I'll give the answer for each one so you can understand how it's "supposed" to work vs what's actually going on here.)

In case 1, a normal `p4 sync` command will update only the files with new revisions.  If the revision you previously synced is the same as the head revision, `p4 sync` won't update it.  This makes `p4 sync` very fast -- you can have a million files in your workspace, and if only one of them has changed since you last sync, only that one file is affected.

In case 2, no `p4 sync` command will update the files, in the interest of preserving your open changes.  To submit your changes to the depot, use `p4 submit`; to discard them, use `p4 revert`.  Again, only the open files are affected by these commands, so a `revert` operation affecting only a few files isn't slowed down by however many other files are in your workspace.

In case 3, your workspace is in an inconsistent state -- Perforce's standard workflow is that any time you modify a local file you should "open" it so that the server can track your local work (and optimize operations like `sync`, `submit`, etc, as well as alert other users who open those files simultaneously to potential conflicts).  If you modify a file locally without modifying it, commands like `sync` will no longer work as well because the state of your client is not known to the server.

You can recover from an inconsistent state by using the `p4 reconcile` command (which will open all the inconsistent files so that you can either `submit` or `revert` them), or the `p4 clean` command (which irrevocably discards the inconsistent local changes, as if you'd done `p4 reconcile` immediately followed by `p4 revert`).  These commands are significantly slower than a normal `sync` operation since they need to scan *the entire workspace* rather than only the changed files, but they are still significantly faster than a `sync -f` since only the changed files are actually re-transferred.